# Queuing yaml build in VSTS API gives unable to resolve reference error

Tags: azure-devops

I'm queueing a yaml build definition in VSTS using PowerShell and it looks like I'm not supplying the correct JSON body for the VSTS API call:

```
$uri = "https://$($accountName).visualstudio.com/$($projectName)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=4.1" 

$body = @{
    "definition" = @{
        "id" = "$($buildDefinitionId)"
        "sourceBranch" = "refs/heads/master"
    }
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
"error","message":"Unable to resolve the 
reference '' to a specific version. Verify the reference exists in the source repository.
```

I can confirm the YAML build definition exists in the project. I looked at a GitHub issue that was similarly filed and it doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code instead:

```
$body = @{
    "definition" = @{
        "id" = "$($buildDefinitionId)"; 
    };
    "sourceBranch" = "refs/heads/master";
}
```

Comment: Wow, it was as simple as moving the sourceBranch property out. Looks like it works, thank you!